# Declare constants inside of enum

Tags: java, enums, constants

I want to create an enum and declare several constants inside of it for inner usage...

```
public enum SearchType {

    static final String TEXT = "text";
    static final String BOOLEAN = "boolean";

    STARTS_WITH(TEXT),
    ENDS_WITH(TEXT),
    CONTAINS(BOOLEAN),
    WILDCARD(TEXT),
    REGEXP(TEXT),
    RANGE(TEXT)


    private String searchType;

    private SearchType(String type) {
        searchType = type;
    }

}
```

unfortunately it can't be done this way. Best solution I've come up with so far is to declare a nested interface to store constants...

```
public enum SearchType {

    STARTS_WITH(Categories.TEXT),
    ENDS_WITH(Categories.TEXT),
    CONTAINS(Categories.BOOLEAN),
    WILDCARD(Categories.TEXT),
    REGEXP(Categories.TEXT),
    RANGE(Categories.TEXT)


    interface Categories{
        static final String TEXT = "text";
        static final String BOOLEAN = "boolean";
    }

    private String searchType;

    private SearchType(String type) {
        searchType = type;
    }

}
```

so I'm wondering if there is a better way to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use an `enum` for the `Categories` as well. If you place this in a top level class, it will look natural.

You have to define your `enum` values before any other constants.

AFAIK This is done to simplify the syntax.  You have the enum values first with a special, simplified syntax, followed by the constants you define.  The need for this is more obvious when you start overriding methods in your constants.

Comment: Thanks! It works even as nested enum(at least compiles)